# Conceptualization Help (Access Relationships)

Tags: ms-access, database-design, relationships

I would like some advice to see if my approach (logic) is correct setting up the relationships for a Referral for Treatment DB.  Rules:

- An Order can only be for one Patient
- An Order can be assigned to more than one Provider
- Patients can have more than one Order
- Providers can have more than one Order

[RelationshipsImg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj4GL.png)

Thanks in advance, any guidance is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: That seems OK to me.

Comment: At this point I've only created the tables and assigned the relationships as shown in the image.  I didn't want to get to do too much if I have the logic wrong to start with.

Answer (score 0):

If patient to order is 1-to-1 then you don't need Order_Patient. You can put the foreign key for patient in Orders. You can't put a foreign key for Orders in Patient because a patient can have multiple orders.

Stylistically, I'd rename Orders to Order to be consistent with the other tables.

Comment: Thank you for breaking that down for me Nicomp. And good insight on changing the name to "Order".  That was also holding me back from the realization that while a Order can only have one Patient, a patient can have multiple Orders ;)

Comment: You're welcome. It's great that you are designing before implementing. You have already set yourself apart from most developers.